# Using Modular Boost from GitHub

Tags: git, boost

I'm a little new to Git, but I've cloned and used a few other repositories before. I've read the documentation on how to clone Boost's git repository, and I know it's more complicated than a normal repository.

Step 1, clone the repository:

```
git clone "https://github.com/boostorg/build.git" Boost
```

Step 2, install the module/modules you want to build.

```
cd Boost
git submodule update --init
```

As far as I know, that should download all modules to the folder Boost/lib, but I don't even have a folder called Boost/lib. I didn't even get an error message.

With that, I'm also wondering how to download specifically the modules I want to use, like boost::filesystem for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a super-project that you need to clone and work from that has (almost) all the current Boost sub-repos linked into it ([Boost super-project](https://github.com/boostorg/boost)). You can find further information on how to work in that clone at the [wiki](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/TryModBoost#InstallingModularBoost). The commands you invoke should look something like this (for non-Windows systems):

```
git clone --recursive "https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git" modular-boost
cd modular-boost
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 headers
```

But if you just want to get the bleeding edge and deal with git, you can also download snapshot archives from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/snapshots/) for the master and develop branches.

Comment: That worked, even though I had tried it. I'm not sure what you did differently from what I did. Now my only question left is if there is a way to download just the modules you want. If not, I'll accept that.

EDIT: I realized you are using a different URL than I. That's what I did wrong.

Comment: @ThatCrazyCarlGuy You are welcome.. Please hit the accept answer button for the benefit of others.

Comment: Sorry about that. I remember hitting the button, but it looks like it didn't register. By the way, I've seen you on the Boost github. Good job. Boost is a great set of APIs.

Answer (score 0):

This repository: github.com/boostorg/build has no submodules. `git submodule update --init` will do nothing.

Comment: That explains why `git submodule update --init` did nothing. Thank you!
I did a little more research now knowing that, and found that the modules exist in their own little independent repositories, like "https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem.git" for example. Could I add this in using `git submodule add https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem.git lib/filesystem`? I tried it in the past, and it put the files there, but it didn't get compiled when I ran `./b2`.

Comment: @ThatCrazyCarlGuy yes that's correct about how to add the submodule, but as far as the compilation is concerned that is a separate problem which has to do with boost (i'm only answering this because it has to do with git)

Comment: Thank you. This definitely gets me farther than I was before. I may need to contact the Boost developers themselves to get a full explanation of how this is supposed to be done.